# Clearing up common terminology for functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, terminology, education

I am currently a M.S. of applied mathematics student and a working TA for an axiomatic set theory course. I have helped teach this course in the past, however in my graduate program, the TA usually teaches a lot of the course to gain experience. We are currently covering maps and I had some questions about common terminology and phrases when talking about functions.

To begin I usually start with the following definition:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. A map $\phi : A \to B$ is a relation such that for each $a \in A$ there exists a unique $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in \phi$.

Then I follow with this remark:

> **Remark**: From the definition of a map if $\phi : A \to B$, the $\phi$ can be viewed as an assignment, to each element $a \in A$, of a unique element $b \in B$.

This sits well, usually, since before we start even talking about sets we cover propositional and predicate logic and the students are familiar with the concept of assigning a truth value to a predicate of some variable(s).

---

Here is where I start to have questions: in many mathematics textbooks for set theory, sometimes one reads "the map $\phi$ sends/maps/associates $a$ to $b$". While in others, such as the ones I have based my teaching style after, one reads "a map $\phi$ assigns to every $a \in A$ exactly one $b \in B$." Are all these sentences equivalent? Meaning if a student asks if saying "the map $\phi$ sends/maps/associates $a$ to $b$ and "a map $\phi$ assigns to every $a \in A$ exactly one $b \in B$" are interchangeable I can answer with: "yes, they are all just different ways of talking about maps". I understand the definition of a map is unambiguous and the important take away is that $\phi$ is a relation such that $(a,b) \in \phi$ means "$a$ is related to $b$" -  but I wanted to clarify some common vernacular.

**Disclaimer:** This was originally posted on Mathematics Educators.SE but I felt I would get more precise answers from the community here.

Comment: The *definition* of what a function is requires the quantifiers. A *specific example* on the other hand, is explicitly given, usually by a formula of the assignment, without any quantifiers (but setting the domain and codomain).

Comment: @Berci - I agree. However, do you agree that saying "the map $\phi$ sends/maps/associates $a$ to $b$" can be used interchangeably with saying  "the map $\phi$ assigns the element $b$ to $a$"? As in, they are equivalent terminology/jargon when talking about maps.

Comment: To this question the answer is yes, these are simply synonymous English terminologies.

Comment: @Berci - I don't believe *assign* is a synonym to *associate*, perhaps you meant they are synonymous when speaking about maps?

Comment: The phrase "the map sends $a$ to $b$" doesn't stand on its own, without additional context, because what are $a$ and $b$? The phrase "the map $\phi$ assigns to every $a \in A$ exactly one $b \in B$" is perfectly clear, though.

Comment: @littleO - See, so if we added a little more context and said "the map $\phi$ sends/maps/associates every $a \in A$ to exactly one $b \in B$, would this be synonymous (in the context of maps of course) to saying "the map $\phi$ assigns to every $a \in A$ exactly one $b \in B$"?

Comment: Yeah, that would be synonymous.

Comment: @littleO - Revisiting this - I never asked exactly *why* these sentences would be synonymous? Is it just because mathematicians agree that they are synonymous?

Comment: I would say that words like "assigns" and "associates" are not "official" math terms and they are not usually given precise definitions. If you press a mathematician to say these things more precisely, then they will simply stop using those words, and just give the formal definition of a function. So when they use those words they are being a little informal. And from my experience of what mathematicians mean when they use these terms informally, I can tell that those phrases would be synonymous. (They had better be synonymous, because they're all supposed to agree with the formal definition.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusion comes from not always clearly distinguishing between a function $\phi:A\to B$ and the graph of $\phi$, which is the set $\{(a,\phi (a)): a\in A\}$. Specifically, a function specifies its codomain while its graph does not.

For example, let $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, g(x)=|x|+1$ and $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^+, h(x)=|x|+1$. Although $g(x)=h(x)$, the functions $g$ and $h$ are different since they have different codomains.

Saying that "the map sends $a$ to $b$" seems to refer to the map's graph rather than the map itself, although the distinction is not usually important.

One way to define a function is as an ordered triple $(X,f,Y)$ where $f \subseteq X\times Y$ satisfying for all $x\in X$ there exists a unique $y\in Y$ such that $(x,y)\in f$.

See [Difference between a function and a graph of a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/442522/793719)